# How to stop Function reassigning Boolean value within loop

Tags: python

Im trying to learn Python via creating a basic language-learning app to test myself. In order to get it to test me with a different word each time I have tried to write a function that generates an intial key ONLY IF it is the first time it is run (after this i have another function which should generate a different key).

In order to do this I have tried to us a Boolean (isfirsttime) which I initially set to False within the main loop of the particular Tkinter window in which this part of the code runs (sorry if I'm not explaining this particulary well am admittedly a total begginer!). 
 Within my function I then check if this value is False and then - it is - i generate a key and pass out this plus the value TRUE.
 Back in the main loop I then assign the value True to the variable isfirsttime. 
 I think that the problem is that in the main loop the isfirsttime is FIRST assigned to False (to get the function checkfirst to work the first time) but this means that every time it is run it resets the Boolean to False. 
 Could anybody explain to me how I can reassign the value of isfirst time to TRUE after the first time the code has run, in a way that will cause the checkfirst function to PASS everytime after that? (I know that my problem has something to do with scope but i cannot figure it out - and have tried functions within functions and endlessly reassigning variables so I'm obviously not getting something here!) 
 Many thanks!

```
isfirsttime == False                       
             def checkfirst():                
                 if isfirsttime==False:
                     for item in categories:
                             newkey=random.choice(list(tempdict))
                             print("key is" + newkey)
                     isfirsttime=not isfirsttime
                     print(str(isfirsttime) + "isfirsttime")
                     return newkey, True
                 else:
                     pass
genkey=checkfirst()[0]
isfirsttime=checkfirst()[1]
```

Comment: What's with `isfirsttime == False` at the top of your code? Is it supposed to do something? What's with your indentation? Could you post code in [such a way that it can be actually run](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: "I have tried to us a Boolean (isfirsttime) which I initially set to False", are you sure?  isfirsttime == False is not an assignement.

Comment: Thanks for the help can't believe I didn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the call like this:

```
genkey, isfirsttime = checkfirst()
```

However, you still need to do something about the second time that `checkfirst()` is called.

Also, reading the comments under your question you need to sort out the assignment to `isfirsttime`:

```
isfirsttime = False         # assign isfirsttime to False              
def checkfirst():
    # stuff omitted
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, really useful! Will change isfirsttime to be equal to false and use the method you described above and hopefully be able to figure out how to stop it calling checkfirst again. Once again thanks for the help, really appreciate it!